# PHP MySQL Insert/Update query returns true but with error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following update:

```
$conn->query_cust("update cms_users set last_login_date = now() where id = " . $_SESSION['USER_INFO']->id);
```

I'm sure the problem is not in the `query_cust` function because I use the same function in a few other forms and they work well. Anyway, here is the definition (with two var_dumps for debug-info):

```
function query_cust($s='',$rows=false,$organize=true) {
    var_dump($s);
    if (!$q=mysql_query($s,$this->con)) return false;
    if ($rows!==false) $rows = intval($rows);
    $rez=array(); $count=0;
    $type = $organize ? MYSQL_NUM : MYSQL_ASSOC;
    var_dump($q);
    while (($rows===false || $count<$rows) && $line=mysql_fetch_array($q,$type)) {
        if ($organize) {
            foreach ($line as $field_id => $value) {
                $table = mysql_field_table($q, $field_id);
                if ($table==='') $table=0;
                $field = mysql_field_name($q,$field_id);
                $rez[$count][$table][$field]=$value;
            }
        } else {
            $rez[$count] = $line;
        }
        ++$count;
    }
    if (!mysql_free_result($q)) return false;
    return $rez;
}
```

When executed, I get a Warning message saying:

```
string(57) "update cms_users set last_login_date = now() where id = 1" bool(true)
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/XX/XXXXXXX/html/core/mysql.php on line 26
```

What worries me is that it returns bool(true) but with (correct me if I'm wrong) a not ignorable warning !? When I copy the update-query manually into for example PHPmyAdmin it works (the user has table update/insert rights).

Just a few info for anyone having the same problem: Locally the code run's without any problems (even with 'error_reporting = E_ALL' enabled), but when executed on the test environment (Godaddy's hosting) the warning shows up.

PS: I'm not so into PHP (I'm from JAVA world) so please have mercy while posting your answers and my stupid sub-questions :) Thanks.

Comment: It should not return true. It should return a resource.

Comment: Are you sure? As on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
"For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error."

Comment: instead of selecting WHOLE dataset and then limiting it using $rows variable you have to utilize LIMIT mysql statement, to get the only rows you actually need. 
Otherwise you will hang your server pretty soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), `mysql_query` returns `true` if the query does not return a resultset. Change:

```
if (!$q=mysql_query($s,$this->con)) return false;
```

to:

```
if (!is_resource($q=mysql_query($s,$this->con))) return $q;
```

Comment: Thanks cbuckley :) this solved the problem. Btw. I got the query_cust function from an online tutorial so I'm sure I'm not the only one you just helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You are running an update query, not a select query. So it returns true because the update succeeded. But there is nothing to fetch with mysql_fetch_array().

If you want to select something you need to provide a select query :)